# Angular 14 An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js does not exist

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, tinymce

When run `ng serve`
it show message:

```
 
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...An unhandled exception occurred: Script file node_modules/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.min.js does not exist.
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...
```

and always loading.

please help me.

This my angular version:

```
Angular CLI: 14.0.6
Node: 16.16.0
Package Manager: NPM 8.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.0.6

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.6
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.6
'@angular-devkit/core            14.0.6'
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.6
----------
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting `node_modules` and re-running `npm install`?

Comment: Can [this](https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues/5015) help?

Comment: it doesn't work  :(

Answer (score 0):

What version of TinyMCE are you trying to use?  The `modern` theme was part of TinyMCE 4 but does not exist in TinyMCE 5 or newer.  If you have something like:

```
 theme: 'modern'
```

...in your TinyMCE configuration you need to remove that.  If you don't state any theme value in your configuration TinyMCE will use its default (which is called Silver in TinyMCE 5 or newer).

If you are module loading TinyMCE you may be trying to import that theme which does not exist so you would need to import a theme that exists in the version of TinyMCE you are using.